# VBA IE 11 Runtime

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer-11

I have coded VBA in IE 11 before, and have been able to work around problems, but on this I keep getting an Error 91 or Error 424. While sometimes it works perfectly.

Unfortunately I cannot share the exact site since its password protected, but I am including the source code that's relevant.

I do option explicit, so there should be no problem with my variables.

These are all the different ways I have tried to fill the box with yesterday's date, and none of them work.

```
html.getElementById("begin")(1).Value = Format(Date - 1, "mm/dd/yyyy") '<-error 91

Set StartDate = html.getElementById("begin")  ‘<- Error 424 or Erorr 80010108
Set EndDate = html.getElementById("end")
Set CampaignID = html.getElementById("campaign_id")
```

These are the 4 different things I am trying, but they all work periodically.

```
StartDate.Item(0).Value = Format(Date - 1, "mm/dd/yyyy")  ‘<-Error 91
StartDate.Value = Format(Date - 1, "mm/dd/yyyy")
StartDate.Value(0) = Format(Date - 1, "mm/dd/yyyy")
Set StartDate(0).Value = Format(Date - 1, "mm/dd/yyyy
```

Source Code:

```
<div class="row form-group">
<div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="pull-left text-left" style="width:115px;margin-left:20px">
                <label for="">From :</label>
            </div>
            div class="col-xs-3">
            <input type="text" name="begin" value="" class="form-control input-sm datepicker" id="begin" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1 text-right">
                <label for="">To :</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input type="text" name="end" value="" class="form-control input-sm datepicker" id="end" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this VBA in another host (e.g. Word/Excel/etc), or VBScript running within a `<script>` block within the HTML itself?

Comment: `getElementById()` returns a single element, so don't attempt to treat the return value like a collection.  `Set StartDate = html.getElementById("begin")` should work assuming the page is fully-loaded and complete, and that `html` represents a Document object.  It might help to show a bit more of your code, including the relevant variable declarations.

Comment: Dai - I am running this in Excel.
And Tim, thanks for that pointer! I wasnt able to find much online about the differences, but after experimenting more, I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I was refreshing the page after I signed in. This reset the permissions and was blocking me from changing any of the text boxes. Not sure why, but it was half of the problem.

Then, I changed the variable editing to run through the whole list of "input"s on the page, as seen below:

```
    Dim CampaignId, StartDate, EndDate, RunReport As Object

    Set StartDate = appIE.Document.getelementbyid("begin")
    Set EndDate = appIE.Document.getelementbyid("end")
    Set CampaignId = appIE.Document.getelementbyid("campaign_id")
    Set RunReport = appIE.Document.getElementsByName("_action_report")

    ButtonNum = 0
    Set objCollection = appIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    While ButtonNum < objCollection.Length
        If objCollection(ButtonNum).Name = "begin" Or _
        objCollection(ButtonNum).Name = "end" Then
            Set objElement = objCollection(ButtonNum)
            objCollection(ButtonNum).Value = Format(Date - 1, "mm/dd/yyyy")
        End If
        ButtonNum = ButtonNum + 1
    Wend
```

This way found the buttons on the page where the `getElementById` failed.

Thanks for looking!